# Continuous integration using git branches

Tags: git, iis, tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity

For every story we use a branch in Git. This works great locally but poses a problem when finalizing a feature as we (currently) only push master to our Test environment (IIS). Note that we are using Git next to TFS as TFS is still our main VCS.

We are using TeamCity to build all our branches. How do you test and review code on a test machine while not polluting the main branch? Create multiple IIS applications for every branch? This could be automated but seems contrived.

To clarify, we need to be able to simultaneously test different versions on our test environment.

Comment: Consider adding both [tfs] and [teamcity] tags.

Comment: To clarify, we need to be able to simultaneously test different versions on our testenvironment.

Comment: If you're using both Git and Teamcity, why do you still need TFS? If you're not using TFS for its full Application Lifecycle Management (ALM) suite, and only using it for version control, why not just get rid of it? In my opinion, TFS is a ***far inferior*** version control system to Git. For a strong argument against TFS for both ALM and version control, see [TFS is destroying your development capacity](http://www.derekhammer.com/2011/09/11/tfs-is-destroying-your-development-capacity.html) by Derek Hammer.

Comment: Also, this question might be a good fit for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) too, since it deals with the software development process.

Comment: We need TFS for procedural reasons; the rest of the release process is still modeled with TFS.

Comment: Agree with confusing however, we do need to work in parallel therefore we need multiple environments that we can deploy to in parallel. This works out of the box using Teamcity, branches in git and webdeploy but we then have a coupling between branch and application.
Of course we can make the mapping in our build process, but I was curious to see how others have solved this problem.

Comment: Ok, came to realize that automatic deployment in our case is Actually not the best solution. We deploy to facilitate testing, however the testers should be able to deploy at will to "any" test slot on the IIS machine.
Therefore, we enabled builds on any branch and have a more generic deploy build that has the build as an artifact dependency which points to an application in IIS. As such we have inverted the deployment procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize, I've created several applications in IIS, one for every dev in the team (dev & test) and then 3 slots for test purposes alone.

In teamcity we have the build run every against every branch, but **do not** deploy automatically anymore. The reasoning is that we allow pulls of our builds but don't force upgrades.

When all dev work on a feature branch is complete we merge into master and then sync immediately with TFS so that our master branch is in sync. This allows us to merge each feature per changeset into the next stage.

Comment: sorry for answering my own question, but I think this is best for reference purposes. If not, pls correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `--dry-run` switch:

> -n, --dry-run
>   Do everything except actually send the updates.

```
git push --dry-run ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that having multiple test version of the same application can be really confusing!!

You can adopt something like the [GitHub Flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html):

- One branch per feature
- When the feature is done you deploy it to the test environment
- If everything is OK you can merge the feature to master

In case this is not a viable solution for you, the only alternative I see is to deploy multiple IIS applications. This can be done relatively easily using a tool like [WebDeploy](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx), but you have to think about a "clean-up policy" to remove obsolete web applications.